# Mother Nature's Broken Heart

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, poetry

> Mother Nature's broken heart
> sighs, and in reaction start
> the tears. The weather without him:
> feminine wrath; Vestal vim.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mother Nature's broken heart

> **earth**  - heart anagrammed (broken) and is Mother Nature

sighs, and in reaction start

> **air** - the start of **a**nd **i**n **r**eaction and composes sighs

the tears. The weather without him

> **water** - w(e)at(h)er removing he and the substance of tears

feminine wrath; Vestal vim

> **fire** - f for feminine + ire and clued by vim

Giving the ancient

> Greek elements and posted on Earth day.

Comment: Exactly right. Well done.